# Using Groupby to group a list and then group them again then based on a quantity

Tags: c#

As Title.

For example, I have a list contains 10 items.

```
Id    Name   GroupId
1     abc     123
2     abc1    124
3     abc2    125
4     abc3    126
5     abc4    123
6     abc5    123
7     abc6    124
8     abc7    125
9     abc8    127
10    abc9    124

Var groups = items.OrderBy(m => m.GroupId).GroupBy(o => o.GroupId);
```

Then I have 5 groups.

Group1 (123): {1, 5, 6}

Group2 (124): {2, 7, 10}

Group3 (125): {3, 8}

Group4 (126): {4}

Group5 (127): {9}

Now, I want to regroup them based on max quantity of a new group.

e.g: if maxQuantity = 4

newGroup1: {1,5,6,4} (4 is because group2 and group3 cannot group inside newGroup1)"They have more than 1 item and newGroup1 only can insert 1 item."

newGroup2: {2,7,10,9} (same explanation as newGroup1)

newGroup3: {3,8} (only left 2 items, then they have to group together.)

Any idea on coding? I wasting 8 hours on sitting chair to think this problem and still counting.

*Another case if maxQuantity = 2

```
newGroup1: {1, 5}
newGroup2: {6, 4}
newGroup3: {2, 7}
newGroup4: {10, 9}
newGroup5: {3, 8}
```

Explanation as same as top example

Comment: I'm a little confused about your rule, why can't the `newGroup1` be `{1,5,6,9}`? (9 instead of 4)

Comment: I think this is where you need to leave linq and go "Old-Fashioned"

Comment: @Sayse not really, I think it's `native fashion`.

Comment: @KingKing, this is because they grouped based on GroupId first. And then group again based on the maxQuantity (still need to take care for the GroupId).

Comment: @KingKing - I was referring to the fact that people have a tendency to think that linq is the be-all end-all of how to do anything with lists

Comment: @Sayse sorry because I cannot explain well.

Comment: king jia, I think I understand, you want to join the final lists together so that they are in groups of max length 4, I just don't think linq is the right thing for this

Comment: @Sayse Right. But still need to group based on GroupId and orderby the GroupId.

Comment: And that bit is fine to use linq for, but now you need to take these groups into your own for/foreach loop and do the final bit yourself, (make a new list, if the next item in the loop can still 'fit' into one of the other lists, add it, otherwise make a new entry in the new list)

Comment: hmmm...I dont know how to code it... Anyone can help?

Comment: The regrouping rule is confusing and frankly makes no sense. What otherworldly property suggest that on a regrouping the item `4` in `Group 4` Id `126` should go into `Group 1` since why not move the `3` from `Group 3` and put the `4` in its place there in `Group 3`???? This question makes no sense at all; hence why there is no answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Basic idea:**

- Sort groups by quantity.
- Iterate through from both sides, combining groups that add up to no more than max quantity.

**Pseudo-code:**

```
sort groups by quantity (biggest group first)
i = 0
j = groups.size-1

while i <= j
  // if the indices met, pick either
  // if the two groups are larger than max quantity, simply pick the larger one
  if i == j || union(groups[i], groups[j]).size > maxQuantity
    output groups[i]
    i++
  else
    output union(groups[i], groups[j])
    i++
    j--
```

If the elements are unique:

```
union(groups[i], groups[j]).size = groups[i].size + groups[j].size
```

**LINQ?**

This is most likely beyond the capabilities of LINQ. As for the C# code, it should be simple enough to derive from the pseudo-code.